# jQuery strange issue with selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a variable that contains the following string:

```
var html = '<a href="http://www.taxibooking.dch/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/4-3.jpg"><img src="http://www.taxibooking.dch/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/4-3-300x202.jpg" alt="" title="4 (3)" width="300" height="202" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-7" /></a>';
```

and then I try to use the following two operations:

```
full_url = jQuery('a', html).attr('href');
tiny_url = jQuery('img', html).attr('src');
```

While the `tiny_url` works fine and returns the value `http://www.taxibooking.dch/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/4-3-300x202.jpg` the `full_url` is always empty.

Can anyone tell me why this is?

Comment: Is `html` a POJS variable, or a jQuery object containing that HTML structure?

Comment: What is the POJS ? I have add an update to me code, may that help

Comment: POJS = Plain Old JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the `a` element isn't *inside* the html you pass but at the first level.

You could do this :

```
full_url = jQuery('a', '<div>'+html+'</div>').attr('href');
```

but it would be more efficient to define and reuse a jQuery object :

```
var $div = $('<div>'+html+'</div>');
full_url = jQuery('a', $div).attr('href');
tiny_url = jQuery('img', $div).attr('src');
```

Comment: dystroy that was the issue. Thanks a lot :) I will upvote in 9 minutes ;) :)

Answer (score 2):

The issue id because `a` is the containing element, so jQuery is trying to find an `a` element within the first `a` and obviously returns nothing.

Instead you can use `filter()` like this:

```
var full_url = jQuery(html).filter('a').attr('href');
var tiny_url = jQuery(html).find('img').attr('src');
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/NavFu/)

Or alternatively you could wrap your HTML in a `div` and keep the jQuery as it is.

```
$html = jQuery('<div>' + html + '</div>');
full_url = jQuery('a', $html).attr('href');
tiny_url = jQuery('img', $html).attr('src');
```

Comment: [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) doesn't do what you seem to think it does. See     http://jsfiddle.net/XtgbR/